# Element has `checked` attributes but isn't checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox, toggle

I am using ThreeDubMedia's drag and drop selection feature to check and uncheck a couple checkboxes. It will check and uncheck them once, but no more than that. What's more, when I look at the elements by using inspect, they start without the `checked` attribute, as they should; they gain it when selected, as they should; and they lose it when selected again, as they should. **However**, this is where it gets strange. If I select it a **third** time, it gains the `checked` attribute, but does not check! And if I select it a fourth time, nothing happens! I have no idea what's causing this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [snag.gy](http://i.snag.gy/AieOg.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you are actually removing the attribute (using `removeAttr()`) instead of just turning it off (e.g. `prop('checked', false)`).

You should be using [**prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).  The following works:

```
if (this.checked) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
} else {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnqHb/12/)

---

Or better yet, as `@Pointy` mentioned:

```
.drop(function( ev, dd ){
  this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnqHb/13/)

Comment: How about just `this.checked = !this.checked;` ??

Comment: That's perfect; I like the second one--very elegant. Why did my method not work?

Comment: @Ian You were actually removing the attribute (removeAttr)